# how to remove keys from an array and store only data in array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to remove label and forming a new array with only value array using lodash.
May i know how can i achive this?

**Input:**

```
[
{label: "Campaign 3", value:3}
{label: "Campaign 1", value:1}
{label: "Campaign 4", value:2}
{label: "Campaign 6", value:5}
]
```

**Output:**

```
[3,1,2,5]
```

Comment: Why would you need lodash for this ? `arr.map(i => i.value)` will work.

Comment: What is your actual question? "I have *A* and I want *B*, how can I achieve this" seems like a veiled "Can someone write this code for me". Please consider including an attempt or specifying exactly what you're having trouble with.

Comment: You can checkout the lodash map method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for Lodash for this. You can use the built-in JavaScript `map` function:

```js
var input = [
  {label: "Campaign 3", value:3},
  {label: "Campaign 1", value:1},
  {label: "Campaign 4", value:2},
  {label: "Campaign 6", value:5},
];

var output = input.map(x => x.value);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any third-party plugin and libraries like **lodash** and **jquery**, you can just use **javascript map** callback function as done above in comment section. If you want the same using lodash then do it as below.

```
  var input = [
  {label: "Campaign 3", value:3},
  {label: "Campaign 1", value:1},
  {label: "Campaign 4", value:2},
  {label: "Campaign 6", value:5},
];


result = _.map(input, function(o) { return o.value; });
```